# Simulate "internal" in Java

Tags: java, android, internals

I would like to reproduce the "internal" C# behavior in Java.
I have three projects and one of them is my "framework" which has a method that I want only this project be able to call.

This method can't be private because it's called outside its class.
So I had to give it a "public" visibility. This means that my other 2 projects that refs my framework can call this method too.

I want to give a compile error when these projects call this method and give this power only for my framework project.

Comment: Wait until Java 9 comes to Android, and your wish will be fulfilled.

Comment: You could use the `protected` keyword instead of `public` if the method is onto called from the same package and sub-classes. Or you could use no visibility modifier at all and achieve "package private" visibility, such that only classes in the same package can access it.